# My mdoel how to map the getters and setters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

showing the error message that method of the return value is never used.

```
public Long getId(){ return id; }
public void setId(Long id){ this.id = id; }

public  void  setQueue(String queue){ this.queue = queue;}
public String  getQueue() { return queue; }

public Number getAnswered(){ return answered; }
public  void setAnswered(Number answered){ this.answered = answered; }


//how to map and where to reffer this getters and setters
```

i am new to spring boot

Answer (score 1):

You have to have this in your class, either private/protected/public/default or none

```
private Long id;
private String queue;
private Number answered;
```

And to use these methods, create a new object of this class and call the method, example you have a class named A that have the above attributes

```
class A{
   private Long id;
   private String queue;
   private Number answered;
}
```

In somewhere else you create a new instance of class A and call the method

```
A instanceOfA = new A();
A.setId(1);
System.out.println(A.getId()); // This will print number 1 to the screen
```

Comment: how it is written in the controller while MCV

Comment: Your class should map with annotation Entity if you want to save it to db or just map it with annotation Component. And then in controller you define new instance by using Autowired annotation then use the object like normal, call the method or whatever you do